# C# variable type

Tags: c#

I am a newbie at C# so please don't get mad at me if this is stupid.
I have a project containing 7 variables :

```
string Monday , string Tuesday , string Wednesday , string Thursday , string Friday , string Saturday  , string Sunday
```

I want all of these variables to have their own specifications , for example

```
Monday.Lesson1 , Tuesday.Lesson5 , Friday.Lesson9
```

And I want those specifications to be like variable , so I can change their data.
Any help ?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "specification"?

Comment: their own variables , if that makes any sense. like imagine you have a variable called Fruits. and in that variable you have your strings like fruit1 , fruit2 , and when you call those strings in a label you could see the names of those fruits , apple , banana.

Comment: The short answer is you are using the words wrong. I _suspect_ what you are interested in is enums and / or classes and / or arrays.

Comment: So you want to declare your own class named `SchoolDay`.  With a `List<Lesson>` as a member.  Make it so.

Comment: I am not sure what is your question about exactly, but as said above you probably want to use classes and/or enums. Based on your question you are a newbie at programming, I can recommend you Brackeys video series on C#, it is really beginner friendly. I think you should watch the whole series but the ones relevant to your question are [classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2hHjpZaSyI) and [enums](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETy3x4XeK9E)

Comment: but as I understand if I use enums the values inside the enum will not have their own data. like             enum MyEnum {       value 1 = "etc."     }

Comment: As a guess of your intentions: create a class called `DaySpecification`. Include properties for `Lesson`, `StartTime`, whatever. Then create a `Dictionary<DayOfWeek, Lesson>` (DayOfWeek is a System enumerated type (DayOfWeek.Monday is a value)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I understand from your question, you want to create a class that stores a day of the week as well as the lessons on that day. A small example program of this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyProgram
{
    public enum Day { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<string> lessonsOnMonday = new List<string>();
            lessonsOnMonday.Add("Biology");
            lessonsOnMonday.Add("Computer science");
            SchoolDay monday = new SchoolDay(Day.Monday, lessonsOnMonday);
        }
    }

    public class SchoolDay
    {
        public Day day;
        public List<string> lessons;

        public SchoolDay(Day day, List<string> lessons)
        {
            this.day = day;
            this.lessons = lessons;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I think you should understand the basic concepts of Object-Oriented Programming and C# as without those you will hardly understand this code. I can recommend you the [tutorial series of Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGD0vn-QIkg). It is really beginner-friendly and he has even more tutorials on C#, but you can find many resources on youtube and the internet in general just by searching.

I recommend that before you try to make a program, you learn some basic concepts.